# How do I get the name of Postscript file object?

Tags: filenames, postscript

Using Postscript, I want to retrieve the name of the file being executed. I know that I can get the file object using 'currentfile', but how do I get its name?

I want to include the name in the document.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ghostscript has a [`.filename` operator](http://ghostscript.com/doc/current/Language.htm#File) that'll do it. No idea about the portability. Tiny viewable example:

```
/Times-Roman findfont
12 scalefont
setfont
newpath
100 200 moveto
currentfile .filename pop show
```

Comment: According to the link, "If the file was opened by the file or .tempfile operator, returns the file name and true; if the file is a filter, returns false." Since `currentfile` is not opened with file or `.tempfile`, `currentfile .filename` returns "false false".

Comment: Assuming you're even using Ghostscript, how are you feeding the Postscript to it? If you're sending it via a pipe or network connection, there's no way any program in any language could figure out what the original filename was, unless you store that in the file somewhere. (Also, did you try this? Apparently files provided on the command line are sufficient for Ghostview to be able to get their name.)

Comment: It's a simple matter for the postscript interpreter to open the input files using a little bit of postscript handling code. So command-line arguments can indeed be opened by the `file` operator (before execution of the user program begins, of course).

Comment: Yes, I am using Ghostscript and Ghostview. I am using Windows with .ps files assigned to Ghostview by double-clicking in File Manager